# dismissing iOS keyboard on tap without breaking table view cell tap functionality

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextview

I want to add functionality to dismiss the keyboard on `UITextFields` and `UITextViews` when the users taps outside the keyboard. I have a view very similar to New Event in iOS Calendar thats a bunch of static table cells, some of which have text fields and some send to a Show view (like the "Repeat" cell in the New Event in the Calendar app).

I tried using the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Looks for single or multiple taps. 
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

//Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

but this breaks the functionality of the cells that tap to segue to a Show. I can get around this by just having the keyboard go down on "return", but I can't do this with my `UITextView` since that adds a newline. The Calendar app dismisses the keyboard in the `UITextView` on what seems to be a swipe up and down, but I'm not sure how to add this functionality myself as I'm new to iOS programming.

Any solutions for getting around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Select your tableView in storyboards.  Then in attributes inspector find keyboard and set to "Dismiss Interactively."  This should allow for the swipe down to dismiss.

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS 10 simulator. Am I missing something? Dismiss on drag works fine.

Answer (score 1):

> The Calendar app dismisses the keyboard in the UITextView on what seems to be a swipe up and down

Indeed it does. And that is what you should do. A text view and a table view are both scroll views. The usual solution, therefore, is to set the scroll view's `keyboardDismissMode` to `.Interactive` or `.OnDrag`. That is how the Calendar does it, and that's how you should do it.

Comment: So I tried `self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .OnDrag` (.Interactive seemed to not do anything for me) and it seems to work as I wanted, dragging up or down dismisses the keyboard in both textfield/view. However when I swipe to dismiss I get this printed in the log `-[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on <UITextEffectsWindow: 0x144d62150; frame = (0 0; 375 667); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x144d07110>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.` Is this something I need to worry about?

Comment: No, that's just a spurious keyboard-related message. If you have time, report it to Apple, but you can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is that you can add `UITapGestureRecognizer` on view, and when a view is tapped then dismiss keyboard just like below.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    //do stuff
}
```